# Python 3.x Proper way to make gameloop in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, game-loop

I am making a game in tkinter, and I was wondering if there was a proper way to make a game loop. With the current gameloop, whenever I update an object's position, It can be blurry. Here is my current gameloop:

```
self.running = True
      while self.running:
          for object1,object2,command,*args in coldetect:
              self.detectcollision(object1,object2,command,*args)

          self.canvas.delete('all')

          for s in cubes:
              s.draw()

          self.root.update()
          self.root.update_idletasks()

          sleep(1/30)
```

where `self.root` is an object of `tkinter.Tk()`, and `cubes` is a list of objects with the function `draw()`

Comment: Use [`root.after(timeout, callback_func)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/1222951)

Comment: @Rawing Sorry, could you elaborate? I seem to be getting nothing but errors.